# Flatten and Convert a Dictionary to a List

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, flatten

```
my_dict = {0: {'alpha': 1510, 'beta': 700, 'gamma': 500},
          1: {'alpha': 1710, 'beta': 900, 'gamma': 700}}
```

This is my dictionary, I want to remove those 0 and 1 keys that you see there and have it become a list format like so

```
my_list = [{'alpha': 1510, 'beta': 700, 'gamma': 500},
          {'alpha': 1710, 'beta': 900, 'gamma': 700}]
```

I want it that way so that I can get a clean JSON output like this

```
[
    {
        "alpha": 1510,
        "beta": 700,
        "gamma": 500
    },
    {
        "alpha": 1710,
        "beta": 900,
        "gamma": 700
    }
]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.values` method of `dict`:

```
my_list = list(my_dict.values())
print(my_list)

# Output
[{'alpha': 1510, 'beta': 700, 'gamma': 500},
 {'alpha': 1710, 'beta': 900, 'gamma': 700}]
```

Comment: Yes, it does, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

> I want to remove those 0 and 1 keys that you see there and have it become a list format like so

The solution @Corralien gave you should be able to do that.

> I want it that way so that I can get a clean JSON output like this

For that, you can use Python's `json` module and use the function `dumps`. It's got an optional parameter `indent` and setting it to 4 usually "beautifies" your json.

This code

```py
import json


my_dict = {0: {'alpha': 1510, 'beta': 700, 'gamma': 500},
          1: {'alpha': 1710, 'beta': 900, 'gamma': 700}}
my_json_string = json.dumps(list(my_dict.values()), indent=4)
print(my_json_string)
```

Outputs

```
[
    {
        "alpha": 1510,
        "beta": 700,
        "gamma": 500
    },
    {
        "alpha": 1710,
        "beta": 900,
        "gamma": 700
    }
]
```

Comment: Yes, I got my desired output, Thank you very much!

Comment: Hmm, the other bug in your selection sort was actually more interesting (can't respond there, as you deleted it).